Fortanix dependency for Java 17
I am upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17
I am using the fortanix dependency com.fortanix:sdkms-client:4.27.2394.
but it is compiled in java 8, I need the one for Java 17.
Opening the class I see Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8).
Thanks in advance!

For which Java version a library is compiled for is independent of the question which Java version(s) are supported. Regarding the class file version Java versions are backwards compatible which means a class file version 52 can be read by all Java versions after 8.
